# About blocking system calls and potential race conditions

Tags: java, multithreading, unix

We are using blocking system I/O calls for network sockets. The behavior we want is when `close()` is called on the socket, the blocking call needs to return and throw an exception ([reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close())),

Looking at OpenJDK, this is how it is implemented. It uses a user [signal](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/solaris/native/java/net/linux_close.c#L60) to wake up the blocking thread. The corresponding signal handler is [No-OP](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/solaris/native/java/net/linux_close.c#L71). Before the blocking call, it [registers the thread](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/solaris/native/java/net/linux_close.c#L125) that may be blocked. When the file descriptor is closed, the closing thread [sends a signal to the blocked I/O thread](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/solaris/native/java/net/linux_close.c#L201), which causes the blocking calls to return with `EINTR`.

However, I still think there is a potential race condition in the following code block [source](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/solaris/native/java/net/linux_close.c#L267):

```
  startOp(fdEntry, &self);  // (1)
  ret = FUNC;               // (2)
  endOp(fdEntry, &self);
```

In the I/O thread, (1) executes, and then the closing thread calls `close` and sends the signal to the I/O thread before (2) starts executing. The signal is received and discarded. When (2) starts executing in the I/O thread, it will make the blocking system call. And at this stage, the fdEntry might be closed, or about to be closed.

Do I understand it correctly? Am I making a wrong observation, or the possibility of a race condition is low so we can safely ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself: it turns out it was indeed a bug. The fix was in the `close` side: we first close the file descriptor, and then signal the blocking thread. If the blocking thread misses the signal and start the blocking call, it will return immediately with `EBADF` because the file descriptor has been closed.